# Microsoft RDP for mac has no resume and reconnects with new session each time after minimized

Tags: macos, azure, rdp

I have been using the Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.18 to work on Azure vms. Every time the rdp on the mac changes to minimized there is no way to get your current window back again. I click on the Windows RDP icon down on the task bar and only get prompted with the initialize connection screen. The causes the server to run out of rdp sessions and am forced to reset the vm.  I am not a pro mac user so it is probably something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forcing an install of the new mac rdp client?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2015/02/25/mac-remote-desktop-connection-error-connecting-to-azure-virtual-machine.aspx#10631510